# SCP, transfer file across 3 computers

Tags: ssh, vpn, scp

I'm having trouble understanding if it's possible to transfer a file from one PC to another passing through a third one.

To explain better my situation:
I have:

- My local PC (PC-1), where I have my source file and that can't connect to the VPN
- A remote PC (PC-2), that is connected to a VPN
- A third remote PC (PC-3), accessible only through the VPN, which is the destination

Can I transfer a file from PC-1 to PC-3 without saving it to PC-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transferring directly from
*local host -> jump host -> destination host*,
you may use the following command:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh $user@jump_host -W $host:22" $local_path $user@host:$destination_path
```

For more information and methods, see the post
[How do I do Multihop SCP transfers between machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers-between-machines)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work, the only thing that I suggest editing in the answer to make it more clear is whether you have to put the user or not in $host: 
`scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh $user@jump_host -W $host:22" $local_path $user@host:$destination_path`

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer.